# Conditional expectation of the number of tails when coins are removed after $m$ tails

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

In a coin tossing game, I have access to infinite number of unfair coins. The game follows as described below.

We take a coin and toss it till we get $m$ tails. Once we get $m$ tails, we remove that coin, sample a new coin and continue the game. The game continues till total number of trials hit $n$. I am trying to find the expected number of tails conditioned on the number of coins used.

The random variable $Y_i=1$ indicates $i^{th}$ coin is the last coin with $m$ tails. The random variable $X_i = 1$ indicates the probability of selecting the $i^{th}$ coin.
Let $C$ be the random variable denoting the number of coins used and for $C=c$, the expected number of tails is

$$
\mathbb{E}(T|C=c) = m\big(P(X_1=1) + P(X_2=1,Y_1=1) +  \cdots + P(X_{c-1} = 1,Y_{c-2}=1)\big) + (n-m(c-1))P(X_c = 1,Y_{c-1}=1)
$$

Now,
$$
P(Y_1=1) = P(X_1=1) = \frac{c}{c+1} \\
P(Y_2=1) = P(X_2 = 1,Y_1=1) = P(X_2=1|Y_1=1)P(Y_1=1) = \frac{c-1}{c} \frac{c}{c+1} = \frac{c-1}{c+1}\\
P(Y_3=1) = P(X_3 = 1, Y_2=1) = P(X_3=1|Y_2=1)P(Y_2=1) = \frac{c-2}{c-1}\frac{c-1}{c+1} = \frac{c-2}{c+1}$$

Following this way, I get

$$
\mathbb{E}(F|C=c) = m\Big(\frac{c}{c+1} + \frac{c-1}{c+1} \dots \frac{2}{c+1}\Big) + n-(c-1)m\frac{1}{c+1}
$$

Is this calculation correct ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For convenience I will use $c$ for the number of *removed* coins. Assuming the coins being fair the probability of $k$ tails is proportional to the number of ways to permute them with heads. Besides we know that $mc\le k<m(c+1)$. Therefore the expected number of tails is:
$$
mc+\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}i\binom n{mc+i}}{\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\binom n{mc+i}}.
$$

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that coins are not fair. Apart from that, can you elaborate the answer ?  I didn't follow the logic completely.

Comment: The expression $$\frac{\binom n{k}}{\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\binom n{mc+i}}$$ represents the conditional probability to have $k$ heads ($mc\le k<(m+1)c$).